Using Regex to Match Values with Prometheus Vector Matching
I have two metrics memory_used with labels
{tenant="1000", instance="testhostb:8888", job="main"}

and instance_operating_state with labels
{group="B", instance="testhostb:8763", job="main"}

I want to filter first one based on the value of second. If they would have same instance, I could use query like
memory_used and on(instance) (instance_operating_state == 0)

But they are exposed by different exporters, and have different ports. Because of this, when I try to use an "on" join like the one above, I get no results because the full instance string doesn't match.
Is there a way to use regex to drop everything after the colon (:) so that I can just join on the first part of the instance name?

The instance names are fixed length as well, so that might be something we can work with. Let's assume that I can't alter the datasource config and have to do this using PromQL and standard Grafana with no plugins.

I removed from the post everything unrelated to question itself, and narrowed the question too. Please don't edit in answer into the question, it's always better to post it as proper answer.

You can use label_replace to introduce new label, based on instance in both metrics and use that label for joining.
label_replace(metric, "hostname", "$1", "instance", "(.+):.+")

will add label hostname that contains everything until last1 colon in the instance label. Demo
So, with assumption that host names in both cases are exactly the same, you can run following query
label_replace(memory_used, "hostname", "$1", "instance", "(.+):.+")
 and on(hostname) 
 label_replace(instance_operating_state == 0, "hostname", "$1", "instance", "(.+):.+")


1 : If you are doing some trickery to instance labels with relabeling this might require additional considerations. For example, if instance doesn't contain : (and thefore doesn't match (.+):.+), no hostname label will be added.

Alternatively (especially if this is common problem for your queries) you can drop port from instance label altogether at the scrape. Check how this is done here. But be very cautious with this, as duplicates in metrics (for example, something like built-in go_info) might cause some troubles.
